# Call C# function when window closed

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I try to call function from c# when user click on "X" in browser but nothing firing close event (I tried: `window.onbeforeunload` and `$(window).unload` and `$(window).unbind`but nothing work.
here is my Java-Script:

```
  <script>
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        PageMethods.endTaskChange();
    };
    $(window).unload(function () {
        PageMethods.endTaskChange();
    });
    $(window).unbind(function () {
        PageMethods.endTaskChange();
    })
</script>
```

And there is my code behind:

```
 [ScriptMethod]
    [WebMethod]
    public void endTaskChange()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["ID"] != null && HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString() != string.Empty)
        {
            long TaskID = Convert.ToInt64(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["ID"]);
            List<BusinessLayer.Tasks> olstTasks = new List<BusinessLayer.Tasks>();
            olstTasks = new TasksRepository().GetByID(TaskID);
            if (olstTasks.Count > 0)
            {
                Authentication oAuthentication = new Authentication();
                if (olstTasks[0].StatusID == 1 || (olstTasks[0].StatusID == 2 && olstTasks[0].ClosedByUserID == oAuthentication.getUser()[0].ID))
                {

                    BusinessLayer.Tasks oTasks = new BusinessLayer.Tasks();
                    oTasks.ID = TaskID;
                    oTasks.ClosedByUserID = oAuthentication.getUser()[0].ID;
                    oTasks.StatusID = 1;
                    oTasks.CloseDate = DateTime.Now;
                    oTasks.CloseNotes = "";
                    new TasksRepository().Close(oTasks);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

is there any help?!!

Comment: endTaskChange method must be static,

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
         PageMethods.endTaskChange();
});
```

or this:

```
$(window).on('unload', function(){
        PageMethods.endTaskChange();
});
```